# Please explain System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(Func<T, int, bool> predicate)

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable, enumerable

I can't make any sense of the MSDN documentation for this overload of the Where method that accepts a predicate that has two arguments where the int, supposedly, represents the index of the source element, whatever that means (I thought an enumerable was a sequence and you couldn't see further than the next item, much less do any indexing on it).

Can someone please explain how to use this overload and specifically what that int in the Func is for and how it is used?

Comment: This one? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb549418.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Rup. I understand now, but something in me rejects that sort of an interface. I can't seem to stand index and sequence in the same sentence. But the link you offered answered my question in that it taught me how to use the method, so, thanks much.

Answer (score 6):

The `int` parameter represents the index of the current item within the *current iteration*. Each time you call one of the LINQ extension methods, you aren't in theory guaranteed to get the items returned in the same order, but you know they're all be returned once each and thus can be assigned indices. (Well, you are guaranteed if you know the query object is a `List<T>` or such, but not in general.)

Example:

```
var result1 = myEnumerable.Where((item, index) => index < 4);
var result2 = myEnumerable.Take(4);
// result1 and result2 are equivalent.
```

Comment: Many thanks for the great explanation, Noldorin. You make an interesting observation. In what cases would you not be sure about the sequence in which the items are returned? Could you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 4):

You can't index an `IEnumerable<T>` in the same way you can an array, but you might be able to use the index to filter the list in some way, or possibly to index some data in another collection which will be used in the condition.

EDIT: As an example, to skip every other element you could use:

```
var results = sequence.Where((item, idx) => idx % 2 == 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, Lee. Sure, I get the point now, but still, to me personally, it doesn't seem very intuitive. I don't know what, but something appears to be awry with that interface.