# LINQ where doesn't accept 1 or 2 parameters

Tags: c#, linq

The following code with a boolean parameter works pretty well:

```
public List<T> SearchByStatus(bool status, List<T> list)
{
    return (List<T>)list.Where(_item => _item.Executed == status);
}
```

But if I want to use something like this

```
public List<T> SearchByCodeType(ECodes codeType, List<T> list)
{
    return (List<T>)list.Where(_item => _item.CodeType == codeType);
}
```

, the IDE throws an error saying `Func<T, int, bool>` doesn't accept 1 parameter.
I researched a bit and found for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288433/please-explain-system-linq-enumerable-wherefunct-int-bool-predicate).
If I now add a seond parameter, lets say

```
public List<T> SearchByCodeType(ECodes codeType, List<T> list)
{
    return (List<T>)list.Where((_item, _index) => _item.CodeType == codeType);
}
```

it says `Func<T, bool>` doens't accept 2 parameters.

The messages itself are correct, but I don't get why it assumes I want to use the overloaded version of Where in the first case and the non-overloaded in the second... Am I doing something wrong?

P.S.: The ECodes-type used is defined as

```
public enum ECodes : int
{
    ....
}
```

May that cause the issue?

Comment: Your `list.Where((_item, _index) => _item.CodeType == codeType)` version should work fine... except for the list cast - should presumably be `return list.Where((_item, _index) => _item.CodeType == codeType).ToList();`

Comment: The original code you've given certainly wouldn't work well - the return value from `Where` *isn't* a list. (Unless you've got your own LINQ to Objects implementation, of course...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of these should work fine:

```
public List<T> SearchByCodeType(ECodes codeType, List<T> list)
{
    return list.Where((_item, _index) => _item.CodeType == codeType).ToList();
}

public List<T> SearchByCodeType(ECodes codeType, List<T> list)
{
    return list.Where(_item => _item.CodeType == codeType).ToList();
}
```

If they don't - please check whether you have `using System.Linq;` at the top, and are using **regular** LINQ (not something obscure like LINQBridge).

You could also use:

```
public List<T> SearchByCodeType(ECodes codeType, List<T> list)
{
    return list.FindAll(_item => _item.CodeType == codeType);
}
```

Note that all of this assumes that you have a suitable generic constraint on `T` such that `T.CodeType` is well-defined - presumably:

```
class Foo<T> where T : IHazCodeType
{
    List<T> SearchByCodeType(ECodes codeType, List<T> list) {...}
}
interface IHazCodeType
{
    ECodes CodeType {get;}    
}
```

Comment: I don't exactly know why but the ToList() has solved my problem. Interesting... Tanks for your time :)